How many Australians died to conquer Gaza and Jerusalem from the Ottoman empire?
In WWI, British infantry and Australian mounted riflemen, supported by armoured tanks and gas WMDs, conquered Gaza and Jerusalem from the Ottoman empire. What was the Australian casualty toll?

May I remind all downvoters that answering your own question is actively encouraged?

Also troops from India, New Zealand, Newfoundland, South Africa, Rhodesia, Egypt, Sudan, Cyprus, Hejaz, France, and Italy (wiki)

"Total Australian casualties in the [Egyptian Expeditionary Force] were just over 4000, with 574 killed in action and another 288 dying of their wounds." (Bou, Australia's Palestine Campaign)

As a lower bound, there are at least 476 identified Australian WWI cemetery graves within Israel/Palestine. (Note that additional graves may not be in major cemeteries, or may have been repatriated, and some soldiers may have been evacuated before succumbing to their wounds, and notwithstanding that some graves have recently been damaged by Israel razing pre-Israel cemeteries.)
As an upper bound, around 17 thousand commonwealth soldiers were lost in the the Sinai-Palestine campaign overall. (Also around 140k horses, "walers" sent from NSW Australia, served in the WWI Desert Campaign and only one returned to Australia.)
